# Phrasal verb "knock off"

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Watching the movie "True Lies" I heard the phrasal verb

> He said he'd **knock off** 100 bucks.

It like lowering the price of something, but does *knock off* have more meanings? Like *knock it off!*? Is it related?

Comment: In the movie, the phrase means exactly "to lower the price by 100 dollars".

Comment: Ah, but does it has more meanings?

Comment: Wiktionary **[lists 8 verbal and 2 noun meanings](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/knock_off)**, including a mention of possible non-idiomatic use (where "knock" and "off" work as separate words), and 3 derived expressions. Oh. And welcome to ELL!

Answer (score 1):

*To knock off* means

- to quit doing something.  *Knock it off* is often said to children to tell them to stop doing something annoying.  Whatver is being asked to be "knocked off" in this sense is typically bothersome or annoying.
- to decrease - the logical meaning is "taking something off of the top".  While the thing being decreased isn't usually too annoying, it's usually something that is desired to be lowered, like a price.
- *Knock* means to push or tap something, and *knock off* can still mean that, e.g. to push or tap something off of something else.